# Command Ordering

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, command-line

I made a user command called `Type` and would like it to appear first in the list of available commands when I type `:t` and then hit tab. Currently, the first command is `TOhtml`, which I've never used.

Other than renaming the user command to something like `TAype`, is there a way to change the order of vim commands?

Comment: AFAIK, there is none. The tab-completion is done not by any specific ordering but just alphabetical ordering. Well, you can mess with the source code of course. But I would suggest binding the command to a key instead, if you use it often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Completion will always show all matches in alphabetical order (well minus the `wildignore` and 'suffixes' settings, but those only affect file matches and not commands).
So the only way to hide the `TOhtml` command is to undefine it ([`:h :delcom`](http://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Adelcommand)) but I wouldn't recommend it, since `TOhtml` is a useful command that allows you to generate a html snapshot from the current document (and works beautifully for e.g. sharing diffs).

You can read about the `:TOhtml` command at [`:h TOhtml`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3ATOhtml), which is a default plugin that comes distributed with Vim.

So it is best to either accept the current state or name your command differently that will sort before the `:TOhtml` command.